# SQL Server : manipulate column value for every Select of a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my application I am querying a SQL Server table `TblUserDetails` a number of times. I have a `DateTime` column `FldDt` in the table.

For each and every select I want to add an offset to the `FldDt` value (say add 5 hrs). I know I can do it by using `dateadd` in each and every queries / sps.

But is there a single point solution for this? (just like trigger - but here we need it while select - not in data manipulation like trigger).

Comment: Have you looked at creating a view that encapsulates the `DATEADD` and using that as your source for queries?

Comment: You can use [computed columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx). However, then you'd calculate it on every select unless you don't specify `PERSISTED`. So i'd prefer an `AFTER INSERT trigger ` or to compute it where i need it with `SELECT`.

Comment: What real problem are you trying to solve? Why do you want SQL Server to magically return values that aren't those stored in the database? How would you update the data if its value was magically altered by 5 hours? Are you having timezone issues?

Comment: SQL Server supports [datetimeoffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx)  to store values *with* their timezone offsets so there is no ambiguity and no need for hour arithmetic.  You can also convert times between timezones with [SWITCHOFFSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx).

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos -   Thx. Exactly this is the case. But the sql server is on a shared server & I think your solution will work in a dedicated server only. If not pl give details

Comment: Does datetime offset work in a shared sql server environment?

Comment: You should simply use a different type, `datetimeoffset` instead of `datetime`. This has nothing to do with how the server is hosted, ie it isn't related to the server's timezone. You simply store the `datetimeoffset` values with explicit timezones.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It seems your suggestion shall work out. I am trying to work it out. As there is a lot of data in the table I am trying to solve it without affecting the existing data... Can you pl provide me the steps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71025/discussion-between-seb-thomas-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have timezone issues, ie you've stored `datetime` values assuming EST but now have to return values to your clients using UTC. Adding an offset to all returned values isn't going to help here because at some point you may have to support another timezone, or enter times in PST that also have to appear in UTC etc. Not to mention that during summer, the offset will have to change by 1 hour

The only reliable solution is to use the [datetimeoffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) type instead of `datetime`. This type corresponds directly to the [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type in .NET and stores the timezone offset together with the date and time values. Comparisons between times in different timezones are possible so you don't have to worry about sorting, indexing etc.

Casting `datetimeoffset` to `datetime` or `datetime2` converts the time to local time, ie in the timezone of your server. This means you should be careful to convert all uses of `datetime` to `datetimeoffset` if you don't want unexpected conversions.

You can convert a `datetimeoffset` to UTC or local time using the `CONVERT` method with a style parameter, eg:

```
convert(datetime2,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET ( ),1)
```

will return a `datetime` in UTC while

```
convert(datetime2,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET ( ),0)
```

will convert the value to local time

To convert your existing dates to `datetimeoffset` you should use the [TODATETIMEOFFSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630335.aspx) function, specifying your current timezone, eg:

```
select todatetimeoffset(getdate(),-300)
```

or

```
select todatetimeoffset(getdate(),'-05:00')
```

As for converting the existing data to `datetimeoffset`, this is a bit tricky because of daylight savings time. You need to check the actual date to decide which offset to apply during conversion.

**Changing the table type**

Changing the type itself is easy:

```
alter table MyTable ALTER COLUMN col1 datetimeoffset NOT NULL
```

This will convert all existing values to UTC values with the same time as the original values, just with a `00:00` offset.

You can change the offset with `SWITCHOFFSET` but **don't** apply it to every row with :

```
UPDATE MyTable
Set col1=SWITCHOFFSET(col,'-05:00') @@garbled-to-prevent-copying
```

You have to check the date and apply the proper offset. The rules change from country to country, or even from year to year. Russia must have changed the rules at least 3 times in the last decade.

Instead calculate the dates you need and use:

```
UPDATE MyTable
Set col1=SWITCHOFFSET(col,'-05:00') 
where col1 between '2014....' and '2014....' or
      col1 between '2013....' and '2013....' ...

UPDATE MyTable
Set col1=SWITCHOFFSET(col,'-06:00') 
where col1 between '2014....' and '2014....' or
      col1 between '2013....' and '2013....' ...
```

**Yet another update**

It may be easier to pre-calculate DST change dates with a library like [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) and store them to an auxiliary table. This will change calculating the offset to a simple a lookup operation.

Noda Time (and other similar libraries) use the [Timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) maintained by IANA, which contains timezones and DST rules for ... I think forever. The database (and the corresponding libraries) is updated regularly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a computed column into the table:

```
alter table TblUserDetails add FldDt5 as (dateadd(hour, 5, FldDt))
```

This is then available to any query that wants to access it.

If you want to keep the same name, then rename the old column and put in the new:

```
sp_rename 'TblUserDetails.FldDT', '_FldDt', 'COLUMN' 
alter table TblUserDetails add FldDt as (dateadd(hour, 5, _FldDt))
```

Comment: Thx. but here in each and evry query or sp I have to change FldDt to FldDt5 - No?

Comment: Not with the second method.

Comment: Why this question? Are you storing UTC times but want them as local times? Use `datetimeoffset` instead of `datetime` for this instead of hardcoding offsets. You specify the timezone when entering the value and don't have to perform any manipulations

Comment: Thx. Exactly this is the case. But the sql server is on a shared server & I think your solution will work in a dedicated server only. If not pl give details

Comment: @SebThomas . . . I have not idea what the issue is with a "shared server".  There is an issue with permissions on the table, but that has little to do with whether the server is shared.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not very nice, but it might work:

1. Create new date column;
2. Update this new column with value of FldDt;
3. Drop FldDt column;
4. Create new COMPUTED column FldDt with the formula you need;
5. Create INSTEAD OF INSERT/UPDATE trigger/s to insert into your new column instead of FldDt.

   ```
    CREATE TABLE test
   (
       FldDt_old DATE,
       FldDt AS  (dateadd(DAY, 5, FldDt_old)) PERSISTED
   );

   SELECT * FROM test

   CREATE TRIGGER tg_test ON test
   instead OF INSERT AS
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO test (FldDt_old)
   SELECT FldDt FROM INSERTED;
   END

   INSERT INTO test (FldDt) VALUES(GETDATE());
   ```

Comment: But when we drop the field FldDt, I have to modify all the queries for insert update operations. no?

Comment: That's why I said to use the triggers. In that case you do not need to modify the queries. Take a look to an example I gave in my answer.